# Testing ViewModel which uses Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines

I have a `ViewModel` which retrieves data from a repository using a Flow. When the flow starts I set a local '`loading`' `StateFlow` object to true.

I have a simple test which passes a fake repository to the `ViewModel`. I call '`fetchItems`' on my `ViewModel` and it calls my repository.

**I would like to assert that the loading `StateFlow` has been set to True** but the assertion executes before the `onStart` function of the flow.

**Edit: I understand that the flow is running asynchronously, I want to wait until the flow has started before making my assertion**

Then once I have tested the loading state being set to true I also want to set the loading state being set to false.

My ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(private val newsInterface: DataRepositoryInterface ) : ViewModel() {
    private val _loading = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val loading: StateFlow<Boolean>
        get() = _loading.asStateFlow()
    
    fun fetchItems(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            newsInterface.getStories()
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .onStart { _loading.update {true } // Loading has started
                .collect { items ->
                    _loading.update { false }   //Loading has finished
                }
    
        }
    } 
}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class GameUITest {

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    @Before
    fun init() {
        viewModel = MainViewModel(FakeNetwork())
    }

    @Test
    fun testViewModel() {
        viewModel.fetchItems()
        assert(viewModel.loading.value == true) // Assertion fails as loading has not been set yet
    }
}
```

Fake repository:

```
class FakeNetwork @Inject constructor() : DataRepositoryInterface {
override fun getStories(): Flow<List<Int>> {
    return flow {
        //Do stuff
        emit(listOf(1, 2, 3))
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Coroutines run asynchronously. You should use the [provided tools](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test) to test them.

Comment: [This page](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test) has some suggestions about creating a fake repo where you can trigger the emissions at will to test intermediate state like what you're doing above. However, I'm not sure about the proper way to await that StateFlow change, since it happens in a different flow. But I have an idea I'll put below. By the way, the fact that you're calling `flowOn` for a flow acquired from a different class is a smell...A publicly exposed flow should not require external classes to have to know to move it to a safe dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about calling `flowOn`. I'm using a fake repo (`FakeNetwork`) and I'm not bothered about the emissions currently, I just want to wait until `onStart` of the flow returned from `FakeNetwork` is called.

Comment: My idea didn't pan out when I tried to write it out. It's kind of a tricky situation. Also, the test requirement is a little bit shaky I think. Theoretically, the first items could arrive before any collectors see a transition in the loading state flow in a correctly behaving app.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this approach.

```
val loadingStates = mutableListOf<Boolean>()
    // backgroundScope ensures coroutine gets cancelled before the end of the test
    backgroundScope.launch { viewModel.loading.toCollection(loadingStates) }

    viewModel.fetchItems()
    loadingStates.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
        when (index) {
            0 -> Truth.assertThat(value).isFalse()
            1 -> Truth.assertThat(value).isTrue()
            2 -> Truth.assertThat(value).isFalse()
        }
    }
```

Full file [here](https://gist.github.com/aleien/4b3ca884c3f304cdee740fb7f8f56740)

What is happening here is that I observe values emitted by `StateFlow` and then check what values were emitted. I use `backgroundScope` because `.toCollection` call on `StateFlow` will never finish and it's coroutine also never finish – which cause test to fail. But `backgroundScope` helps with closing if for test (: It's kinda the same approach usually used for Rx-testing with their `TestSubscriber`, that also gives access to all emitted values.

Also found out that Google [kinda suggest](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/test#continuous-collection) same approach. Actually I got an idea for background scope from that page (: